# How does ROC work with SVM?

Tags: classification, scikit-learn, svm, supervised-learning, roc

Could someone please explain how ROC works with SVM?
Specifically i'm using `RocCurveDisplay.from_predictions(y_test, y_pred, ax=ax[1])` which works fine.

Since the data for `y_pred` is not probabilities, but rather a vector that contains 0 or 1, is threshold constantly 0.5?